# OAuth Error using Yelp API

Tags: javascript, oauth, yelp

I have a sample app that is using Yelp to retrieve reviews and contact information.  It was working perfectly until this week.

I'm now getting this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: OAuth is not defined

```
function addmarker(lat,lng, id, name, comments){

var yelpcontent = '<h4>' + name + '</h4>';
var phone = '';
var address = '';
var city = '';
var state = '';
var zip = '';
var rating = '';

var terms = name;
var near = 'Indianapolis,IN';
var cll = lat + "," + lng;
var accessor = {
    consumerSecret: auth.consumerSecret,
    tokenSecret: auth.accessTokenSecret
};
parameters = [];
parameters.push(['term', name]);
parameters.push(['location', 'Indianapolis, IN']);
parameters.push(['cll', cll]);
parameters.push(['callback', 'cb']);
parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_key', auth.consumerKey]);
parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_secret', auth.consumerSecret]);
parameters.push(['oauth_token', auth.accessToken]);
parameters.push(['oauth_signature_method', 'HMAC-SHA1']);
var message = {
    'action': 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search',
    'method': 'GET',
    'parameters': parameters
};
OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce(message);
OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);
var parameterMap = OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters);
parameterMap.oauth_signature = OAuth.percentEncode(parameterMap.oauth_signature)
$.ajax({
    'url': message.action,
    'data': parameterMap,
    'cache': true,
    'dataType': 'jsonp',
    'type' : 'get',
    'timeout': 5000,
    'success': function(data, textStats, XMLHttpRequest) {


        address = data['businesses'][0].location.address;
        city = data['businesses'][0].location.city;
        state = data['businesses'][0].location.state_code;
        zip = data['businesses'][0].location.postal_code;
        phone = data['businesses'][0].display_phone;
        rating = data['businesses'][0].rating_img_url_small;
        yelpcontent = yelpcontent + '<p>' + address + '<br/>' + city + ', ' + state + '  ' + zip + '<br/>' + phone + '</p><p><strong>Yelp Rating</strong></p><p><img src=' + rating + '></p><p><strong>Personal Review</strong></p><p>' + comments + '</p>';

    },
    'error': function(data, textStats, XMLHttpRequest) {
        console.log(name + ' ' + 'did not work');
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        yelpcontent = yelpcontent + '<p>' + comments + '</p>';
    }


});
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is not defined by default in Javascript.

You have to add it to your page.

Use this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/sha1.js"></script>
```

You can see a full example [here](https://github.com/kelseyGWC/donuts/blob/9d25fd17fb26f22ef71cfc96e9c7d588bc88415d/index.html).

Comment: I have those in my html file and it still isn't working.  :(

Comment: Can you check 1. <script src=/> is before your code. 2. Your site is hosted on https?